# Gradle Failed to resolve: commons-io:commons-io:+

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

When syncing Android project with gradle in android studio , it fails resolving
the packages shown in the screeshot below .

[image: Gradle fails to resolve the packages]

here's my build.gradle :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dmbteam.cityguide"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 4
        versionName '4.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.+') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    compile project(':pinterest_lib')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

under repositories, I usually find that I end up having to have a chain something like this:

```
repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
}
```

In other words, it 1st tries to use your local maven repo, then the specific maven repo/mirror, and then falls back to jcenter as a last resort.